# Feyncalc : problem with diracreduce/diracsimplify. BUG?

Tags: feyncalc

I am new to Feyncalc and I am facing the following problem. I am doing the following:
I set `q3=-q2-q1;`

Then I write

```
Pair[LorentzIndex[k], 
Momentum[q3]] - (-Pair[LorentzIndex[k], Momentum[q2]] - 
 Pair[LorentzIndex[k], Momentum[q1]])) // DiracReduce
```

and I get

```
FV[q1, k] + FV[-q1 - q2, k] + FV[q2, k]
```

Now if I multiply the above with a gamma matrix, let's say for instance GA5 i.e.

```
 (Pair[LorentzIndex[k], 
Momentum[q3]] - (-Pair[LorentzIndex[k], Momentum[q2]] - 
 Pair[LorentzIndex[k], Momentum[q1]])))GA5 // DiracReduce
```

I get zero as I am supposed to find.

Is this is bug? I cannot make the first expression equal to zero. And similar things happen with more complicated expressions.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica SE. Please note, the use of the `Bugs` tag is only for confirmed bugs, that is, where a possible bug is confirmed by other community members and a consensus is reached. Please do not use that tag for suspected bugs.

In addition, while you might get an answer from the community re: FeynCalc here, in general this is for discussion of the products from Wolfram Research.

For third-party tools/add-ons, you are generally better served in their respective fora, in this case the FeynCalc forum at https://feyncalc.github.io/forum

Comment: You can use `// Calc` to simplify it.